# Morphia Entity with embedded BasicDBList fails on IterableConverter.decode

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

I m having an entity like this:

```
    public class Entity {

    @Id
    private ObjectId id;

    private BasicDBList data;

    public ObjectId getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public BasicDBList getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(List<Map<String, Object>> data) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(data, "data");
        this.data = new BasicDBList();
        this.data.addAll(data);
    }
}
```

I m setting the data using an ObjectMapper, from json, to List, like this:

```
 List<Map<String, Object>> data = this.jsonMapper.readValue(JSON, List.class);
```

Saving works fine. When I try to call BasicDAO

```
public T get(final K id) {
    return ds.get(entityClazz, id);
}
```

I get an IndexOutOfBoundsException in IterableConverter.decode when it tries to call

```
final MappedField mappedField = mf.getTypeParameters().get(0);
```

Do I need to treat BasicDBList within Entities in a special way?

Mongo Java Driver Version 3.0.2
Morphia Version 1.0.1

It used to work before with Mongo Java Driver Version 2.12.4 and Morphia 0.108

Comment: Is there a reason you don't declare the data field directly as List<Map<String, Object>> data?

Comment: yes, because you need an embedded DBObject and you can not put the @Embedded annotation on a List, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21860258/morphia-listmapstring-object-return-embedded-element-isnt-a-dbobject-on-fi/21861826#21861826

Answer (score 0):

You might running up against this [bug](https://github.com/mongodb/morphia/issues/784).  Can you try with a 1.1.0-SNAPSHOT build and see if that fixes it for you?

Comment: I ve tried with 1.1.0-SNAPSHOT - it is still broken.

Comment: do you have can say when it will be fixed?